# React-Native Expo Built App Doesn't Get the Latest Javascript

Tags: react-native, expo

Ok, I have a problem with expo build. Please let me know if you need more details. Basically, the project I am working on is NOT detached. It is just using Expo.

So I publish it. Let's say the javascript bundle version is 0.17, and I am publishing a breaking change to 0.18.

When I load the app from Hockey App, the javascript bundle is clearly not 0.18 because I don't see my breaking changes. Then, I close the app and re-open it, and the JS bundle is updated.

The build script is:
exp build:android

[exp] Android:
[exp] APK: [AWS LINK] apk has been generated, it took 0 seconds

Then, I get an AWS link to the APK, which I download and upload to Hockey Apps.

How should I diagnose this problem?

Exp version is 44.0.0

Answer (score 1):

It is the way it works in Android. First time you open your app after you publish, the code is downloaded in background. Next time it will run the new code.
Quoting [the documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/publishing.html):

> Updates are handled differently on iOS and Android. On Android, updates are downloaded in the background. This means that the first time a user opens your app after an update they will get the old version while the new version is downloaded in the background. The second time they open the app they’ll get the new version. On iOS, updates are downloaded synchronously, so users will get the new version the first time they open your app after an update.

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks!

It still seems strange to me because if I build a new Android version and deploy it, I'd hope that it would bundle the new version together with the .apk.